# Unique user ID in a Pylons web application

Tags: python, pylons, cassandra, uuid

What is the best way to create a unique user ID in Python, using [UUID](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html)?

Comment: The previous URL was to an older version of the uuid module; I've replaced it with the documentation at python.org.

Answer (score 8):

I'd go with uuid

```
from uuid import uuid4
def new_user_id():
    return uuid4().hex
```